# Sign Extension, When to stop?

Tags: terminology, bit

Today, we learnt about sign extension to solve the problem where adding positive number to another positive one gives a negative.

But my professor didn't mention at all when we should use it and how much extension should I do?
How may I know when to stop?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "use sign extension"?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I think there is some confusion in your question. You don’t add two positive numbers to get a negative one (this will cause an overflow). You add two signed numbers to get a signed number.

Secondly, I assume that two’s complement representation for signed numbers is used.

Sign extension is required when you need to add numbers that come from different sized sources. As an example, when you have a signed 8 bit value and need to add it to a signed 32 bit value, the 8 bit value needs to be extended to 32 bit value.

Answer (score 2):

You would extend to a convenient bit size.

For example, in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension), the example given is extending a 10 bit number

```
11 1111 0001
```

To sixteen bits.

```
1111 1111 1111 0001
```

Sixteen bits is used because it is a common size for an integer type in many programming languages.  You need the sixteenth bit to be 1 to indicate a negative number, because that's how two's complement works.

You can do the same for 32 bit integers, or whatever size is appropriate.

Sign Extension is required when converting smaller integers to larger ones.   See [here](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/Numbers/U77_0160_sign_extension.htm).

Comment: But how much exactly, my professor showed example where we summed two positive numbers (using two complement) and got one negative cause we didn't extend the number

Comment: @user128250 you extend the smaller sized number to the number of bits of the bigger sized number. I’m talking about the number of bits in the *representation* of the Numbers, not about the absolute value of the numbers. E.g.  a number represented in 8bits is extended to 32 bits in order to add it to another 32 Bit number.